# IndexedDB callback not updating UI in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-app, indexeddb, db.js

I am using the following library to access IndexedDB in Angularjs on a new Chrome App: https://github.com/aaronpowell/db.js

When I try to update the UI on App startup by using this :

```
db.orders.query().all().execute().done(function(results) { 
        $scope.ordercount = results.length;
});
```

in my main.html I have used the ordercount variable as:

```
Orders : {{ordercount}}
```

However, the UI is not updating unless I do ng-click or any other ng-* events. All I need is to show number of orders when my app is loaded. I tried $scope.apply(), but it throws error saying apply() is not available.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are getting the values from out side of the angular js you need to do it like this,

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
  $scope.ordercount = results.length;
})
```

Comment: Damn! I was using $scope.apply() instead of $scope.$apply(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you access $scope from out side of the angular world. You should get scope object first if you want to notify angular that the data had been updated.

```
//assume you have a controller named "dbCtrl" e.g., <div id="container" ng-controller="dbCtrl"></div>
angular.element($("#container")).scope().$apply(function(){
  $scope.ordercount = result.length;
});
```

Hope this is helpful.