# Most efficient way to query ydn-db in a joining way

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, ydn-db

**Setup**

I got stores called '*mapNodes01*', '*mapNodes02*', ..., '*mapNodes70*'

Each holds a number of nodeIDs (keyPath *nodeID*)

I got another store called 'data' that holds values for all available nodeIDs (keyPath *nodeID*)

It is setup like this because the mapNode stores hold different overlapping combinations of nodeIDs. Storing the values of the data store to each mapNode store would be ugly since i need to download and refresh the data table every hour (~7000 nodes).

**Question**

```
SELECT * FROM mapNodes01 JOIN data ON data.nodeID=mapNodes01.nodeID
```

How can i do what the above sql query does with ydn-db effectively?

I need to iterate through the set afterwards to call some functions (drawing svg in my case).
Most important is performance.

i found this > *[How do I do an JOIN-type query in IndexedDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547954/how-do-i-do-an-join-type-query-in-indexeddb)*
but i would prefer a code example since i read through all of it and am not a pro in things like that

Answer (score 1):

Currently you will have to use `ydn.db.algo.SortedMerge`, which is very difficult to use. Hopefully I will finish query module, in that case you just write multiple `where` clause for any equal join.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I managed to stuff the data in every store and stay below 5mb for now.