# ng-repeat not working with merged array objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this based on the [ydn-db package](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/doc/query/join-query.html):

```
var db = new ydn.db.Storage('Trans');

    var iter_supplier = new ydn.db.IndexValueIterator('stops', 'stop_id');
    var iter_part = new ydn.db.IndexValueIterator('times', 'stop_id');
    var req = db.scan(function(keys, values) {
        var SID = keys[0];
        var PID = keys[1];
        // console.log(SID, PID);
        if (!SID || !PID) {
            return []; // done
        }
        var cmp = ydn.db.cmp(SID, PID); // compare keys
        if (cmp == 0) {
            // console.log(values[0], values[1]);
            var merged = angular.extend(values[0], values[1]);
            console.log(merged);

            $scope.results = merged;
            // $scope.$apply(function() {
            //     $scope.results = merged;
            // });

            return [true, true]; // advance both
        } else if (cmp == 1) {
            return [undefined, SID]; // jump PID cursor to match SID
        } else {
            return [PID, undefined]; // jump SID cursor to match PID
        }
    }, [iter_supplier, iter_part]);
```

Console in browser results looks like this:
[image]

And I'm trying to loop through with ng-repeat as:

```
    <div class="medium-6 columns" ng-repeat="result in results">
        <div class="card hoverable">
            <div class="content">
                <span class="title">{{ result }}</span><small class="float-right">{{result.stop_id}}</small>
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <p>Times: {{ result.arrival_time }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I get nothing in the html with ng-repeat. It doesn't seem to loop through. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you telling the angular.extend to store those extended values? This is the docs for `angular.extend` : `angular.extend(dst, src);`. I don't see where you stored them into `merge`

Comment: @theblindprophet updated with full code.

Answer (score 0):

`merged` appears to be a single object, currently printed out on each iteration. Do you mean to be setting `results` to that single object or would you be looking for something like `$scope.results.push(merged)` instead to build up a list of results?

It does look like you want a list instead of a single object, but if you don't, and `results` is going to be a single object/dictionary instead, you would loop through the keys and values using `ng-repeat="(key, value) in results"`.